# Struggling to find kinetic energy for Lagrangian

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, lagrangian-formalism, rotational-dynamics

The system I am looking at is follows.

[image]

To find the Lagrangian $T-V$, I need $T$, which is the sum of the kinetic energies of the three masses shown (rods are assumed to be light).

I know that the velocity of the two small masses in the plane of the page is $a \dot{\theta}$. I also know their velocities into/out of the page is $a \sin \theta \Omega$ (perpendicular distance from axis of rotation OB is $ a\sin\theta$).

$M$ is constrained to slide on the vertical shaft OB, but I'm struggling to calculate its vertical velocity.

Any help on figuring out the velocity of $M$ would be much appreciated.

Comment: 'I also know their velocities into/out of the page is asinθΩ', with the way the problem is pictured I would assume that their angular velocities are all simply $\Omega$, you would want to use that instead of tangential velocities as it would just complicate the working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical height of Mass $M$ is $const.+2a \cos\theta$, so vertical velocity is?

Comment: Wow that was obvious. Thanks.